# Add object to array in class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I have a list of products (unordered list which I apply at the beginning and it shows on screen) and after click on one of them for example: milk, app should add it on screen to list "to buy". But it shows on the screen after I click on another element or second time on the first one. It also not working when I only console.log() in addProduct

```
import React from "react";

import commonColumnsStyles from "../../common/styles/Columns.module.scss";

class ProductsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { productsToBuy: [] };

    this.addProduct = this.addProduct.bind(this);
  }

  addProduct(index) {
    let newProduct = [
      this.props.productsToDisplay.filter(
        (currEl, currIndex) => currIndex === index
      ),
    ];
    this.setState({
      productsToBuy: this.state.productsToBuy.concat(newProduct),
    });
    this.props.sendAddedProductsToParent(this.state.productsToBuy);
    console.log(this.state.productsToBuy);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={commonColumnsStyles.App}>
        <header className={commonColumnsStyles.AppHeader}>
          <p>Products list</p>
          <ul>
            {this.props.productsToDisplay.map((currProduct, index) => (
              <li key={index} onClick={() => this.addProduct(index)}>
                {currProduct.nazwa}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductsList;
```

I have tried setState (in function addProduct) with .concat. It appears immediately when I've used .push method but after click on second element this.state.productsToBuy.push is not a function.

After all I display this products by map method in another function component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```js
addProduct(index) {
  const toBuy = Array.from(this.state.productsToBuy);
  toBuy.push(this.props.productsToDisplay[index]);

  this.setState({productsToBuy: toBuy});
  this.props.sendAddedProductsToParent(toBuy);
  
  console.log(toBuy);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is an async operation. `this.state.productsToBuy` is not
updated until the next render. Save the result of the `concat` in a local variable and pass it to `sendAddedProductsToParent` instead.

Comment: If i want use function component, should I write this "two steps" operation?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code:

```
addProduct(index) {
     
    
         const toBuy = Array.from(this.state.productsToBuy);
          toBuy.push(this.props.productsToDisplay[index]);
        
          this.setState({productsToBuy: toBuy});
          this.props.sendAddedProductsToParent(toBuy);
          
          console.log(toBuy);
    
    }
```